# Desenhar mesmo objeto javascript em canvas distintos

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Criei uma função padronizada para acelerar o processo de desenho em um projeto que envolve canvas múltiplos.

> Agradeço a colaboração de bfavaretto https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto

**Vejam a função: (ela funciona corretamente)**

```
var drawIt = function (canvasCtx, drawObj, x, y) {
    drawObj.onload = function () {
        canvasCtx.drawImage(drawObj, x, y);
    };
};
```

Chamei os diversos canvas no script: (e foram inicializados corretamente):

```
var c1Canvas = document.getElementById("c1");
var c1Ctx = c1Canvas.getContext("2d");

var c2Canvas = document.getElementById("c2");
var c2Ctx = c2Canvas.getContext("2d");

var c3Canvas = document.getElementById("c3");
var c3Ctx = c3Canvas.getContext("2d");

var c4Canvas = document.getElementById("c4");
var c4Ctx = c4Canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Vejam fragmento HTML5:

```
<div class="gfwrapper">
    <canvas id="c1" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c2" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c3" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c4" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

E deste ponto criei objetos para as imagens que deveriam ser adicionadas ao Canvas:

```
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "http://folhaz.com.br/cms/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/carnaval-300x237.jpg";

var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "https://www.google.com.br/images/srpr/logo11w.png";

var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "http://folhaz.com.br/cms/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/sky-tv.jpg";

var image4 = new Image();
image4.src = "http://folhaz.com.br/cms/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/web300x180px1.jpg";
```

**Porém, para a minha surpresa, não consigo adicionar o mesmo objeto de imagem em canvas diferentes.**

Vejam o código abaixo.

```
function drawScreen() {
    drawIt(c1Ctx, image1, 0, 0);
    drawIt(c2Ctx, image2, 0, 0);
    drawIt(c3Ctx, image3, 0, 0);
    drawIt(c4Ctx, image4, 0, 0);

    drawIt(c4Ctx, image1,100,100);
}

drawScreen();
```

A image1 foi adicionada inicialmente ao c1. Ao tentar adicioná-la ao c4, a image1 é apagada do c1 e desenhada no c4. Gostaria que a imagem fosse mantida em c1, sem precisar renomear o objeto.

**Alguém sabe um workaround para isso? É possível?**

Segue JSFiddle para ajudar: http://jsfiddle.net/LeoTheTitan/vV69K/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa de um objeto separado para a imagem (não se preocupe, ela será carregada do cache):

```
var image5 = new Image();
image5.src = "http://folhaz.com.br/cms/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/carnaval-300x237.jpg";

// ...

drawIt(c4Ctx, image5, 100, 100);
```

Uma alternativa é clonar a imagem antes de passá-la à função:

```
drawIt(c4Ctx, image1.cloneNode(), 100, 100);
```

Comment: Clonar o node funciona muito bem. Mais uma vez obrigado pela sua ajuda. Deixe seu contato, posso ter oportunidades de trabalho no futuro que sejam interessantes para você.

Comment: Obrigado. Se quiser entrar em contato no futuro, me procure aqui no site, ou no chat do site. Estou sempre por aqui.